# how to enable escapeshellarg() in .htaccess this is possible

Tags: php, apache, shell, php-ini

shall i enable this php function escapeshellarg() in .htaccess . This php function is in the disable list in php.ini of the server for some security reasons.

So please suggest that how shall i enable it from the .htaccess file. or give me alternative solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't override `disable_functions` in a `.htaccess` file as this setting is `PHP_INI_SYSTEM only`.

You could write your own flavour of `escapeshellarg()` but if this is disabled, `exec()` and `system()` are probably too, so this is a bit pointless.

You probably are on a shared server and would need to go either VPS or Dedicated to set your very own PHP configuration.

Answer (score 0):

escapeshellarg()
The PHP escapeshellarg() function must be enabled.

exec()
The PHP exec() function must be enabled.

Comment: please explain to OP how to enable it, where are the configuration files (if any)